# How can i automate my aws ecs build and dockerisation using circleci

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, automation, amazon-ecs, circleci

I am trying to automate my project on AWS, through circleci, But not able to find proper resources, I tried many resources but none worked for me, I want to automate the docker build and aws ECR setup.

this blog was very explanatory but not working on 2.0 circleci version

http://www.savvyclutch.com/devops/continuous-deployment-to-aws-ecs-and-circle-ci/

can anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many resources on circle-ci documentation itself.
Here are some Links:

https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-aws-ec2-container-service/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/leveraging-circleci-and-aws-codedeploy-for-continuous-integration-workflows/